# Spam flag declined, even w/my comment calling out company affiliation

Tags: discussion, spam

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167580/storing-files-nosql-vs-sql/31169072#31169072) as spam, as the poster is an enterprise architect for the company who makes the product (and I called this out in a comment), and there's no disclosure of such (aside from the "Sales warning" comment, which is not the same as disclosing affiliation).

My flag was declined, as the moderator found no evidence to support this. Should I be including actual links to affiliations, such as [LinkedIn profiles](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/buzz-moschetti/68/758/37a), when their StackOverflow profiles don't disclose affiliations either?

The question itself will in all likelihood be closed for being opinion-based, but I'd like to improve on my future flaggings of spam-type answers.

Comment: So what exactly is that post selling or promoting?

Comment: The *(Sales Warning)* is a disclosure of sorts, it is the *question* that is the issue here, which is now rightfully closed. I declined it as this is pushing the definition of spam to breaking point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I saw the answer, along with follow-on comment about "One set of monitoring, management, query fabric, authentication, entitlements, volume/scaling, etc. " as a sales pitch. And as far as *(Sales warning)* - I don't necessarily equate that with company affiliation. That all said: I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The user *did* disclose their affiliation, of sorts:

> (Sales warning) MongoDB is technically and economically very attractive in this regard, and you can start small and scale infrastructure as demand requires it.

That is the sum total of the promotion going on here. This is *at the very best* borderline promotion.

But note that this was posted on a question asking for a comparison between RDMSes and MongoDB; it is the question that is more at fault here. Just close the question and move on. At most let the user know it is not a good idea to answer low-quality off-topic questions.

Save your spam flags for actual blatant spam, we get enough of that kind of trash as it is.

Comment: @DavidMakogon keep in mind that a "helpful" spam flag actually levies some very serious punishment on the person who posted the spam.  Most notably a 100 rep deduction.  As a result mods tend to err on the side of declining these very borderline cases so they don't punish an innocent poster.

Comment: Now it intrigues me even more, that the post has been removed? Hmm...

Comment: @9kSoft The question is a terrible one anyway, so there is no use keeping it around.

Comment: @9kSoft: I deleted the question, it wasn't worth keeping.

Comment: @psubsee2003: A mod clearing a community spam flag as helpful doesn't trigger the 100-rep penalty.  That's only done after six community flags or one mod flag.